# SQL-Like queries in CRYPTDB doesn't work

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption, database, cryptdb

I have downloaded and built [Cryptdb](https://github.com/CryptDB/cryptdb) and it works well. Most of queries on encrypted database run without any issue but, the query with `LIKE` key word receives an error.

```
mysql> select * from pptbl;
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
| 1    | ali   |
| 2    | arbab |
| 3    | ava   |
| 4    | azim  |
+------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.12 sec)

mysql> select * from pptbl where name LIKE '%ali%';
ERROR 1105 (07000): Identifier not found: 'oINVALID'
FILE: main/Analysis.cc
LINE: 782
```

and Related encrypted results:

```
QUERY: select * from pptbl  
NEW QUERY: select `pbpcr`.`table_JMVMTSUOXQ`.`FETRAWCXAQoEq`,
`pbpcr`.`table_JMVMTSUOXQ`.`cdb_saltEDYOFRHNTM`,
`pbpcr`.`table_JMVMTSUOXQ`.`LGDQMZOLRAoEq` from `pbpcr`.`table_JMVMTSUOXQ`
ENCRYPTED RESULTS:
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|FETRAWCXAQoEq       |cdb_saltEDYOFRHNTM  |LGDQMZOLRAoEq       |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|6564397473536819806 |13839409992861282053|?]???i?Q0?o~?????rqw??$\??3??c6?|
    |4201181374583641407 |5838989347444454725 |?$@ur?????????????[?^9??V S_5??^|
|1649188046741762720 |9525321359430614429 |``???L??w|??f?C>?????4<????[????|
|16881031136507617701|7294557497133907357 |p?r?my?[???E`?2cLE/?.???E??????~|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

and the result of following query:

```
mysql> set @cryptdb='show';
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------+
| _database | _table | _field | _onion | _level | id   |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------+
| pbpcr     | pptbl  | id     | oEq    | RND    | 1082 |
| pbpcr     | pptbl  | id     | oOrder | RND    | 1083 |
| pbpcr     | pptbl  | id     | oADD   | HOM    | 1084 |
| pbpcr     | pptbl  | name   | oEq    | DET    | 1085 |
| pbpcr     | pptbl  | name   | oOrder | RND    | 1086 |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------+
5 rows in set (0.43 sec)
```

Comment: Are you sure they support "LIKE". It was my understanding that CryptDB only supports a subset of SQL. **UPDATE:** Looks like they do support a subset of 'LIKE' (see [page 5](https://people.csail.mit.edu/nickolai/papers/raluca-cryptdb.pdf)).

Comment: Also, you are likely better off asking about this on the cryptdb-users mailing list. Not that we don't want you on our site :) but I'm just trying to be honest with you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about CryptDB and what it currently supports, and not about cryptography

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is the [main contributor reply](https://lists.csail.mit.edu/pipermail/cryptdb-users/2015-June/000409.html):

> The latest released version of CryptDB no longer supports the LIKE
>   operation. Feel free to contribute to CryptDB and extend it to support
>   this operation. You can find **an older implementation (disabled)** in the
>   code, which we did not have the chance to port to the latest system.

Comment: Interesting, glad you found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Cryptdb](https://css.csail.mit.edu/cryptdb/) doesn't support *LIKE* queries.  You can try using *in* and *not* in queries.  It supports *update*, *in* and *not* in queries but not *like*.

Comment: According to the  CryptDB paper [I linked to](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26423/sql-like-queries-in-cryptdb-doesnt-work#comment61279_26423), they do, if you are doing keyword matching. Won't work for regex like searches though.

Comment: @Prakruti As the contributors claimed they used like queries: here [https://github.com/CryptDB/cryptdb/blob/7678bc98d3054f1418371779c6d1050cd1a88b2e/eval/apps/openemr/CRYPTDB_queries.txt] they used `SELECT id, invnumber, transdate, shipvia, intnores FROM ar WHERE invnumber LIKE '%.%' ORDER BY id`

Comment: looks like they disabled LIKE queries in recent releases